# Loop through a list of elements & send data by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of **li** elements. each **li** element contains some paragraphs of text.

To view an **element** content, my app should **click** this **li** element, then a **popup window** is opened and the app retrieve the text from the popup window then post it to a server using **$.ajax**.

To do so I am using an **each method** to loop through all **li** elements one by one.
My purpose is finding a jquery or javascript way to wait every time so informations are retrieved from an li element and then when all data are posted using ajax, move to the next li and so on.

```js
listItem.each(function(index) {
  if (myCondition) {
    console.log('item with index: ' + index + ' is skipped');
  } else {
    listItem.click();
    setTimeout(function() { // Wait 1 second until the popup is opended
      popupWindow.animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).height()
      }, $(this).height() * 10, getData);

      function getData() {
        // ...
        // ...
        postData(data);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
});

function postData(data) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    // ...
    // ...
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myList">
  <li class="list-item">.......</li>
  <li class="list-item">.......</li>
  <li class="list-item">.......</li>
  <!-- ...... -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a loop you could recursively call function that processes one item and pass in `next()` in ajax promise resolve

```
// initial call
processItem($('.myList li:first'));

function processItem($li) {
  if (!$li.length) {
    return; // none left
  }

  var $next = $li.next();

  if (condition) {
    console.log('item with index: ' + $li.index() + ' is skipped');
    // recursive call assumed here also
    processItem($next);

  } else {
    $li.click();
    setTimeout(function() { // Wait 1 second untill the popup is opended
      popupWindow.animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).height()
      }, $(this).height() * 10, getData);

      // get the data to post

      // use promise returned from postData to start process next item
      postData(data).then(function() {
        processItem($next)
      });

    }, 1000);
  }
}


function postData(data) {
// must return the ajax promise 
 return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    // ...
    // ...
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl ! It seems working wery well now.

Comment: Great...was worried I might have missed something minor. Trickier when you can't test it yourself

Answer (score 0):

You might `await` each `$.ajax` call. Instead of `listItem.each` (which will iterate *synchronously*), use a `for` loop, which allows for easy *serial* asynchronousness. Note that you have to be inside an `async` function to use `await`. For example:

```
(async () => {
  for (const li of $('.list-item')) {
    await $.ajax( ... )
  }
})();
```